# Pardot form handler success page redirect

Tags: html, pardot

Using Pardot form handlers can I send back form inputs as part of the success page?

i.e. if the form has `firstname` and `lastname` I would like my success page to be like `http://www.mysite.com/success?firstname=myvalue&lastname=anothervalue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the form handler configuration you can turn on "Enable data forwarding to the success location" and you should get exactly what you are looking for.